# php native functions like min() do not support fixed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, spl

I was wondering why the native php function like `min($array)` do not support `Spl Fixed Arrays`. Okay `gettype` will say it is an object, however it still contains array data.

There are so many useful php functions for arrays, but in order to use them I have to use an extra method `$fx_array->toArray()`. Whenever you decide to use fixed arrays you have to think.. do I need to use `toArray()`?

Comment: It is probably implemented differently and min function accepts array and not SplFixedArray (different types). toArray() should do the trick

Comment: Strange example. If you initialize a static array, you'll have to pass the size. Thus using a function like `min()` on it doesn't make sense, since you already know the size. However there is a method [`SplFixedArray::getSize`](http://php.net/splfixedarray.getsize.php).

Comment: @galchen yes I believe the same thing, obviously min() is quite low level, and for efficiency reason it probably makes some assumptions that for fixed array are not true. on the other hand, fortunately toArray() works perfectly.

Comment: @feeela no it is not about the size, is about the smallest/minimum element. In addition is not only the min function, the same goes for the rest of them, max, array_sum, implode etc, they will all complain!

Comment: for itertors that don't have a method to provide an array: `min(iterator_to_array($iterator, FALSE))` - http://php.net/iterator_to_array

Answer (score 3):

As `SplFixedArray` implements `Iterator`, it is easy to extend the class itself:

```
class SplFixedArrayOnSteroids extends SplFixedArray
{

  public function min(){

    $min = $this[0];

    foreach($this as $value)
    {

      if($value < $min)
        $min = $value;

    }

    return $min;

  }

}
```

Ok I know it would be less portable and all, but welcome to PHP.

Comment: Technically `$min` should be initialize as `+Inf` :)

Comment: @Jack no there is no need for `+Inf`, because `$min = $this[0];` is fine and smart I could say.

Comment: @Melsi And what if there are no elements in the array?

Comment: Ha ha.. welcome to PHP, this is so true some times. Although someone will not probably use min this way, the example it self is nice for showing that we can extend that class.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this doesn't answer the Q? :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony It doesn't really explain why it won't work otherwise, but this alternative to the problem is worthy of mentioning imho :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `SplFixedArray` is not final, therefor you can extend it.

Why is that a problem?
`min()` would need to iterate it, and while it could, it may trigger unexpected behavior. Take the `SplPriorityQueue` class as an example which removes items upon iteration. Someone could easily extend `SplFixedArray` and do something like that.

Comment: Nice that you mention the "unexpected behavior"

Comment: This seems a bit subjective, since it's not substantiated that this is indeed the reason behind not supporting Traversable or ArrayAccess.

Comment: Well, it seems logical to me, since you're required to implement a `count` method in order for count to work. Why should be any different for other functions? But yeah, this is just my opinion :)